# Integrate BigBlueButton for video conference in Angular App

Tags: angular, bigbluebutton

I am working on an elearning Angular app and I want to integrate a video call using Big Blue Button. Is there any one who can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate BigBlueButton for video conference in Angular App, you need to install the BigBlueButton-JS-SDK using the following command:

npm install --save @types/bigbluebutton-js-sdk

After the installation is complete, you need to import the BigBlueButtonSDK module in your Angular App:

import { BigBlueButtonSDK } from '@types/bigbluebutton-js-sdk';

After that, you can use the BigBlueButtonSDK methods to connect to the video conference server and start the video conference.

Comment: I tried to install it but I got this error:     npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fbigbluebutton-js-sdk - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/bigbluebutton-js-sdk@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.